# Sencha touch 2 Ext.factory scope

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope, sencha-touch-2, factory

How can I access `this.something()` from inside a method?
My code needs to process the `this.something()`s return value before letting it in to the `Ext.factory()` method.

I'm getting the correct value from `this.something()` **only** when I write my code like this:
`Ext.factory(config, Ext.Container, this.something());`.

But instead I need to do few things to the `this.something()`s return value before letting it in. How can I achieve this? I know that I could write code to get the value back from the instance and modify it, but I think it's not very convenient way to achieve this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to put some behavior in your function, you can try an anonymous function :

```
var scope = this;
Ext.factory(config, Ext.Container, function(){
    var temp = scope.something();
    //logic
    return temp;
}());
```

I don't really understand why you don't want to put this logic before calling the factory though.